# Instalación de Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

¿Cómo podría instalar Visual Studio sin que me pida nada de almacenamiento en el disco local C:, y descargar absolutamente todo en otro disco?

Answer (score 1):

En el mismo instalador del Visual Studio te permite modificar el directorio de instalación del IDE, solo es cuestión de revisar las opciones de Visual Studio Installer.

Answer (score 1):

Uno de los pasos de la instalación es "Installation Locations", o bien, "Ubicación de la Instalación"... En ese paso indicas la ruta de instalación del Visual Studio y de la caché de instalción. Simplemente define la unidad en la que deseas instalar.
Si tienes más dudas, revisa la página de Microsoft (Paso 7): https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/visualstudio/install/install-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

Comment: Buenas, mi pregunta mas que nada, es instalarlo sin usar el disco local C:, en otro disco.

Comment: En el paso de la instalación que te comento defines la ruta de instalación... Por defecto está en C: pero tú puedes elegir cualquier otra unidad en tu equipo... Así como la carpeta de esa unidad en donde deseas que se instale...

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/es-es/feedback/forum/fdbk_commsite-feedback_other/el-instalador-no-me-deja-instalar-visual-studio-en/38eab4d8-2537-4f1c-92e6-a3cabf1b54e7, aquí encontré un problema similar al mío, el caso es que aunque cambia la ruta de acceso, siempre me pide algo de espacio en el disco local C:, aunque las futas las ponga en otro disco.